# UIWebView path depends on previous pressed button Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController (A)`, containing n buttons. all buttons map to other `ViewController(B)` containing a `WebView` to show a different PDF.

Instead of creating n `ViewController`, I would know how to change path according to which button was pressed.

---

my wrong tries:

1- use tags of buttons in ClassB `viewDidLoad:(id)` sender (I add sender)

```
([sender tag] == 1)
//Action
```

2- access public variable from other class

in class A.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController
{
    @public
    NSString *path;//was var
}
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString* path;
```

ClassA.m

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender{
    path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"];
}
```

in class B:

```
ClassB *obj ;
NSURL *url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:obj->path];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webview loadRequest:request];
[_webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: r u using storyboard or xib]

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm using storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `ClassA.m`

```
 - (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender{
           path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierName" sender:self];
  }


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender       {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifierName"]) {
    classB *clsB =segue.destinationViewController;
    clsB.typeofSelect=path;

   }
}
```

in your `class B.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *typeofSelect;
```

in your `Class B.m`

```
@synthesize typeofSelect;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if (typeofSelect )
{
  NSURL *url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath: typeofSelect];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webview loadRequest:request];
[_webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
 }
else
 {
  // no path found;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you need the help I surely I assist with you

Comment: Thank so much, pdf is not appearing on simulator and Warning: Attempt to present <classBViewController> on <classA> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: simple bro , change this method viewdidload to viewDidappear,just wait I modify my answer

Comment: Sorry, same warning :(, I have changed classA to navigation controller, but does not work

Comment: now I changed the **prepareForSegue** method please update and check

Comment: same warning ,but finaaaly, it works, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something like:

```
//implement prepareForSegue at the ViewController with the buttons
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"button1Segue"]) {
        DesitnationController *controller = (DesitnationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //set some public variable to know which button called the view
        //or directly set a URL or do whatever you need to do. Example:
        controler.pdfUrl = @"http://www.pdfsite.com/pdfForButton1.pdf";
    }
}
```

in the destination ViewController just use the variable you have set.

If you are not working with segues, you can create, push the UIViewController and set the variable in the `IBAction` method.

Comment: I meant you should set a variable of classB, not set a member variable of classA. Also `@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString* var;` will automatically use a member variable called `_var`, the variable you created called `var`will not be used by the property unless you define it in the setter/getter (you should be getting a warning for that)

Comment: thank you to make me notice conflicting variable names, I have defined a variable of classB with same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you can differ which url you want to show depending upon a numeric digit, then using tag is an ideal option.

First declare a simple property in ViewController(B) like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSInteger tagValue;
```

Then simply, provide all your buttons with specific tags and connect all the buttons to the same `IBAction`. Let's consider your `IBAction` is `buttonPressed:`, your code will be something like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadNextPage" sender:sender];
}
```

Lastly, in your `prepareForSegue:` method, do the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loadNextPage"]) {
       UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
ViewControllerB *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
controller.tagValue = [button tag];
 }
}
```